# Detect wifi IP address on Android?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I need to determine if the Android device is connected to Wifi, and if so, obtain its Wifi IP address.

I know how to use ConnectivityManager to determine whether the active network is a Wifi network, and I know how to use java.net.NetworkInterface to iterate over the available network interfaces and get their IP addresses.

What I don't know how to do is determine which IP address belongs to the Wifi network, if there is more than one address found. Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
public String getIpAddr() {
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
   WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
   int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

   String ipString = String.format(
   "%d.%d.%d.%d",
   (ip & 0xff),
   (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
   (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
   (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

   return ipString;
}
```

**Please Note**: You need to add `android.permission.INTERNET` and  `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` as `<user-permission/>` to access the code.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: the INTERNET permission is not needed; just the ACCESS_WIFI_STATE (at least on 4.1.1)

Comment: Awesome!!! This was the only code which worked for getting the local Wifi-LAN IP of my smartphone. I really searched hours.

Comment: You can use Formatter.formatIpAddress instead of doing the formatting by hand.

Comment: Is there a way to get the IPv6 Wifi address?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this code.

```
ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//To fetch the state of the Wi-Fi network in the device
Boolean isWifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting(); 

WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo(); 

//To fetch the name of the Wi-Fi network to which the device is connected
String wifiName = wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

Comment: This is useful in that it gives me the name of the Wifi network, but that's not really what I was looking for. When I enumerate the network interfaces, they have names such as "tiwlan0". I need to associate that name with the active network.

Answer (score 1):

```
static final int IP_ADDRESS_LENGTH = 32;

  public static Integer getSystemWifiIpAddress(Context context)
  {
    WifiManager wManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wInfo = wManager.getConnectionInfo();

    int ipAddress = wInfo.getIpAddress();
    if (ipAddress == 0)
      return null;
    return ipAddress;
  }
```

Comment: How can an IP be an int?