# Wifi IP address in Android and Wi-fi locks

Tags: android, ip-address, android-wifi

Can someone let me know when will the `WiFi IP address` change in an android device?

If I acquire a WiFi Lock, will the IP address remains the same till I disconnect?

Comment: (go)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975473/detect-wifi-ip-address-on-android]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IP address changes according to AP Subnet like any hardware with network adapter.

`WifiLock` allows an application to keep the Wi-Fi awake (if device stay in stay-by ...) and not refers to IP change

Comment: Your IP address changes according to AP Subnet. Can you please explain? If Wi-Fi is awake, will the IP address be the same as the one initially assigned? @Fess

Comment: lets say you have Access Point (AP) with `Gateway 192.168.2.1`. Since your device connected to AP you have `IP 192.168.2.2` If device entered to sleep and your WiFi manager disconnected, after wake up you can fetch the same IP in case if no other devices took it. `WiFiLock` just makes your device to be connected to AP during sleep state

Comment: I am relatively new to Android. If I implement a wifi lock and wake lock, the IP address will not change. Am I correct? @Fess