# How can my android app detect range of ip address

Tags: java, android

I want my android app to detect a range of ip address basically, from 192.168.150.0 - .255 and i want it to put it in void onStart, i created an array but it doesnt work.

here is my java class for the main activity

```
MediaPlayer playMusic;

@Override    
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    for(int array;array < 256;array++)
    try {

        if("192.168.150")
    }            
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    //playMusic.release();
}

/**
 * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
 * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
 * while interacting with activity UI.
 */
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSystemUiHider.hide();
    }
};

/**
 * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
 * previously scheduled calls.
 */
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}
```

}

and this is my java class to detect wifi when the app is open

```
public class WiFiChangeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private String LOGTAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "WiFi Status Changed");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG,
                        "Wifi is connected: " + String.valueOf(networkInfo));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so u want to create a ip address array.

Comment: First of all, the `WiFiChangeBroadcastReceiver` will fire even if your app is closed. Your app does not need to be open. Secondly, What do you mean by detect IP Address. How are you detecting them ? And finally, what exactly is not working ?

Comment: @Nithinlal yes i want to make ip address array

Comment: @ShivamVerma by doing the `WifiChangeBrodcastReceiver` it just mean that my app is automatically detect the ip address? and finally, i dont know how to create array for ip address range which is from 192.168.150.0 - 192.168.150.254 thanks

Comment: whose ip address do you want to detect ? the device on which you're running the app ?

Comment: the device that has already been connected to a wifi @ShivamVerma

Comment: so, you want the ipaddress of your own device ?

Comment: @ShivamVerma need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get the IP Address :

```
public String getIpAddr() {
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
   WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
   int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

   String ipString = String.format(
   "%d.%d.%d.%d",
   (ip & 0xff),
   (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
   (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
   (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

   return ipString;
}
```

**Please Note**: You need to add `android.permission.INTERNET` and  `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` as `<user-permission/>` to access the code.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975955/1239966

Comment: can i put `public String getIpAddr() {
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
   WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
   int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

   String ipString = String.format(
   "%d.%d.%d.%d",
   (ip & 0xff),
   (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
   (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
   (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

   return ipString;
}` in my `@Override    
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    for(int array;array < 256;array++)
    try {

        if("192.168.150")
    }            
}`

Comment: Just put this method inside your class and call it. You'll get your ip address as String in return. `String myIP = getIpAddr();`